# Unable to resolve CORS error on AJAX call to Express API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to access express api using ajax and I am not able to solve the CORS error. When I disable it on the browser it works but I want to make it work without it also.

Back end code:-

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express();

app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Request incoming...")
    let data = [
        {
            name: "Krish",
            age: 23,
            hobby: "Football"
        },
        {
            name: "John",
            age: 23,
            hobby: "Basketball"
        }
    ]
    res.send(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"data":data})))
});

app.listen(5000, ()=>console.log("Listening on port 5000"))
```

Front end code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <table id="myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Hobby</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Click to get Data</button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn").on('click', function(){
                    console.log("Function called")
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:5000/",
                        type: "GET",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        //data: JSON.stringify({"data":"Hardik"}),
                        headers:{ "charset":"UTF-8",
                                    "Accept": "application/json",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        beforeSend: function (x) {
                        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                            x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                        }
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response.data)
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status) {
                            console.log("Error " + status)
                        }
                    });
                })
            })
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Error Message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'null//undefined'.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, and Access-Control-Allow-Methods are permissions the server respond to you with. They are not what you send to the server.  You are supposed to send Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers

Comment: Read up on CORS here if you like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

Answer (score 2):

These are **response** headers:

> ```
> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
> "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true",
> "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
> ```

It does not make sense to send them from the client to the server.

The server must grant permission to the client. The client cannot grant itself permission.

By adding those headers you turn a simple request into [a preflighted one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) as the browser must ask permission to make a request with custom headers.

The cors module you are using *can* be [configured to allow preflighted requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight) but in this case you should **avoid making the preflight request** in the first place.

**Remove the custom headers from the client.**

Answer (score -1):

The CORS error is occurring because of the response from the backend.
As others have mentioned sending those headers in your request does nothing, what you need to do it send those from your backend/api. I see you have some sort of CORS library imported on the backend but evidently it's not working correctly so ensure that it's configured in the right way and installed fully or just paste on the headers you have in your request.